# Java 8 Optional orElse whereas isPresent

Tags: java-8, option-type

I am very confused about the `orElse` method of an optional. 
I have used following code, which calls the `orElse` case every time although the optional value is present:

```
Optional<NotificationSettings> ons = userProfileDao.loadNotificationSettingsByTransportType(type);
NotificationSettings notificationSettings = ons.orElse(createNotificationSettings(profile, type));
```

If I rewrite the code to the following, the correct path (`ifPresent`) is chosen:

```
Optional<NotificationSettings> ons = userProfileDao.loadNotificationSettingsByTransportType(type);
NotificationSettings notificationSettings = ons.isPresent() ? ons.get() : createNotificationSettings(profile, type);
```

I thought the `orElse` is doing the same like my example in the second case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid evaluating the alternative value use `orElseGet`:

```
NotificationSettings notificationSettings = 
    ons.orElseGet(() -> createNotificationSettings(profile, type));
```

There's no magic.  If you call a method like `orElse`, all its parameters get evaluated eagerly.  `orElseGet` gets around it by receiving a `Supplier` to be evaluated lazily.